# BigQuery raises Pagination token expired on first getQueryResults

Tags: google-bigquery

We're seeing sporadic cases (4x today) of query errrors that BigQuery raises at the firs attempt to call getQueryResults (e.g. without a pagination token). The error is:

HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/.../queries/job_...?alt=json returned "Pagination token expired">

The status of the job on a get() call returned 'DONE'.

This is the output of a bq wait for the failed job:

Waiting on  ... (0s) Current status: DONE
Job

Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration   Bytes Processed

---

query      FAILURE   24 May 08:00:06   0:00:00

Errors encountered during job execution. Pagination token expired

Note that this happened within seconds after submitting the query job.

Any ideas on what could be happening here?

Comment: More details: this problem started to occur once we started using decorators (e.g. table@t1-t2) as a cost optimization.

Comment: Does the error occur at every getQueryResults attempt where you are using decorators in the query? Or only from time to time?

What if you try to catch the error in your code and ignore it, does it actually return query results; since the status is done, maybe it was complete and the error message or erogenous?

Comment: Sharing a job id helps in transient cases like this

Comment: job_2BpTu9HeMhl5I1-EG-YTS1Tk_iA

Comment: I was able to narrow the problem down the a SQL as simple as:SELECT customer.id as customer_id FROM [tablename@1431820800000-1431856800000] WHERE 
    created >= '2015-05-17 04:00:00' AND created < '2015-05-17 06:00:00' GROUP BY customer_id;   This results always in the expired token error

Comment: Just ran it now: Query Failed
Error: Pagination token expired
Job ID: triggeredmail:job_r-Tb06dlX3872CdkyJwIEExYNBI

Comment: Note that using decorators is not a guarantee for this particular error, when joined with another subselect that uses a decorator while the first does not, the query completes ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is just a bad error message. The problem is that BigQuery only supports decorators within the last 7 days. For the query used in the job mentioned above, the time range specified was 30 days in the past.

The error should have said something like "invalid table decorator, trying to read from a time XXXX in the past".  Instead it said "Pagination token expired". The reason for this is that pagination tokens under the covers use a similar mechanism to table decorators, and the wrong message got plumbed through.

So we'll fix the error message, but there is also a problem with the query that should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks again Jordan. The code was just attempting to use decorators for the single month cases, not taking the 7 day restriction in consideration. Apologies for the user error. The error message would help though.