# BigQuery completed job returns 404 on getting query results (immediately after)

Tags: google-bigquery

We run a set of queries on a 2 hour interval which have been running for a week now without issues. Recently on 2015-06-04 00:00:26 UTC we had a job (job_OY8G2_I-F6dbXFW93GdB94wc_W0 ) marked as done, but we received a 404 HTTP exception when trying to get the query results.

I understand that results only last for 24 hours but in this case the query results are obtained right after the job status is 'DONE'.

bq wait job_OY8G2_I-F6dbXFW93GdB94wc_W0 also claims the job was a success.

Is this a situation we should code for (e.g. wait for the job completion, then do a test query to make sure the results can be accessed before paginating through the results and resubmit the entire job on a 404?)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423818/bigquery-raises-pagination-token-expired-on-first-getqueryresults

Comment: Hopefull someone from BQ engineers will check these, as I am seeing frequent Questions here about this particular issue.

Comment: Yes, this is one of these cases where it's not clear what the course of action should be. 404s generally shouldn't be retried I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a brief period yesterday (June 3) where a small percentage of requests to BigQuery were rejected with a 404 response. It should have cleared up by about 8pm Pacific Time.

This was due to a problem with a configuration change that was caught before it rolled out widely, but it took a while to undo.

Pentium10 if you have seen something similar before, it is likely unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jordan. We'll keep our exception handling as is.